# Key Value Property help IOS

Tags: ios, cocoa

I am making an iPhone app that gets data from a web service and stores it in Core Data. All these properties have keys to identify them in a dictionary. I have an `NSObject` class of all the properties.

I have now decided to add one more property not being gotten from a web service called `checkMark`. I have also added it to this method. The problem is whenever I try and set the `checkMark` property in a method like this : `[s setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:check] forKey:@"checked"];`, `s` being a `managedObject` I get an error saying `"the entity Course is not key value coding-compliant for the key "checked"`. How do I fix this?

```
- (id)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // Set the property values
        _iD = [[dictionary valueForKey:@"Id"] intValue];
        _isCurrent = [[dictionary valueForKey:@"IsCurrent"] boolValue];
        _checkMark = [[dictionary valueForKey:@"checked"] intValue];
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the type of checkmark property

Comment: what is `s` ? Is it dictionary or something else ?

Comment: this means in dictionary there is no key called "checked"

Comment: You have to define a `@property` for `checked` in whatever class the object `s` is a kind of.

Comment: I do have a property for checked and its an NSInteger, And S is an NSManagedObject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make the entity Course key value coding-compliant for the key "checked".

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/Compliant.html

Basically that means it must have a setter `setChecked:` and a getter `checked`. The usual thing is to have a property with synthesis of that setter and getter.

Incidentally, the fact that the log message is talking about an entity Course suggests to me that the thing you are calling `dictionary` and casting as an NSDictionary might in fact not be a dictionary at all, but might be something else, i.e. an NSManagedObject. Just a guess... You might do some logging / breakpointing to see what's really happening here.

Comment: is there any way to set the property without using a key. Can I do something like [s setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:check] without using a key?